# Difference between EMV tags and ISO 8583 Data Elements

Tags: emv, iso8583

Just wanted to know what the difference between EMV tags and data elements is

For example EMV books specify PAN to be contained in 5A tag however ISO 8583 mentions PAN to be present in DE2 element

Does that mean that these Data Elements are nothing but a collection of these emv specified tags ?

For example DE2 contains the 5A tag?

Comment: With respect to the above question would an auth request from the acquirer to an issuer contain DE02 for the PAN or would it contain tag 5A?

Comment: It would contain the information contained in tag 5A, formatted according to the rules of your ISO dialect. Which may or may not be the same data bytes.

Comment: Hi and to be clear would an authorization request that is being transported from the terminal to acquirer be in ISO8583 format or emv format?

Comment: It depends on the payment scheme, you need to ask the acquirer, only they can tell you what information they expect and how they expect it to be formatted. _If_ what is spoken between terminal and acquirer is in fact an ISO8583, the message is by definition in ISO8583 format, but in no way does this exclude that the payload in some field could just be an EMV element.

Answer (score 2):

Both are specifications. ISO8583 deals with the request response messages between different institutions, as per ISO. Each payment schema( eg. Visa, MasterCard, .. ) have their own implementation of ISO8583 which is to be followed when sending/receiving messages to/from them.

EMV is a consortium of payment schemes, and it has specification as to how chip and terminal should communicate with each other, 3D secure, QR code specifications etc. So mostly dealing the acquirer side.

Comment: th respect to the above question would an auth request from the acquirer to an issuer contain DE02 for the PAN or would it contain tag 5A?

Comment: yes, it will. similarly a few others: DE03.1 - 9C, DE04 - 9F06